# Consolidating single rows of data from multiple sheets into one - looping the macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook containing a number of worksheets which track predicted and actual project spend throughout the financial year. The same project is in each row in each worksheet. I've been asked to group all of the financial data held on each project together in one master spreadsheet and have been using this macro, which is working well:

```
Sub CombineData()
Dim Sht As Worksheet
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sht.Name <> "Master" Then
Sht.Select
Range("A:A").Insert
Range("A91").Formula = "=Mid(Cell(""filename"",B1),Find(""]"",Cell(""filename""))+1,255)"
Range("A91").Copy
Range("A91").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("A91:U91").Copy
Sheets("Master").Select
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sht.Select
Range("A:A").Delete
Else
End If
Next Sht

End Sub
```

However, I have approximately 180 rows of data which I need to consolidate into one sheet and am currently having to change the row number within the macro manually. Is there a way I can make the macro automatically move on to the next row once it has completed one? i.e. once it has copied and pasted all row 91s from individual workbooks into my master workbook, it repeats the process with all row 92s without me having to manually alter the code?

From what I've read online I'm guessing it may be possible to achieve this using a For loop. Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to VBA and I can't work out how to incorporate this into my macro. Any pointers anyone could give me would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Sub CombineData()
Dim shMaster As Worksheet, Sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set shMaster = Sheets("Master")
shMaster.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Clear
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sht.Name <> "Master" Then
        With Sht
            LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Columns(1).Insert
            .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Formula = "=Mid(Cell(""filename"",B1),Find(""]"",Cell(""filename""))+1,255)"
            .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
            .Range("A2:U" & LastRow).Copy shMaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
            .Columns(1).Delete
        End With
    End If
Next Sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you want to do '*copied and pasted all row 91s from individual workbooks into my master workbook, it repeats the process with all row 92s*' but you have supplied no termination point.

This code does what you want (assuming you adjust the 9999 to something more reasonable) but it would probably be better to perform all of hte operations on one worksheet then move on to the other than all of the 91's then all of the 92's, etc.

```
Sub CombineData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Long
    For rw = 91 To 9999
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            With ws
                If .Name <> "Master" Then
                    .Columns("A").EntireColumn.Insert
                    .Cells(rw, "A") = .Name
                    .Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, 21).Copy _
                        Destination:=Worksheets("Master").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    .Columns("A").EntireColumn.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next ws
    Next rw

End Sub
```